# error More than one row with the given identifier was found in Spring-Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

How can i retrieve all the records from a child table in which i had given many-to-one in child and one-to-many in parent. like,

my parent class have mapping like..

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountMaster")
private Set<AccountsData> pinAccounts;
```

and in my child i have..

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "mId")
private MasterData accountMaster;
```

While i tried the following code i got the error `More than one row with the given identifier was found`

my code was ..

```
Criteria myCriteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AccountsData.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("IsDeleted", false));
        return myCriteria.list();
```

I want to get all the entries from child table. But its showing that error. How can i make it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: for a one child, there should be one Parent, in your case it may be multiple in database, cross check in DB